# How to Monitor Requests of my Application

Tags: java, http, request, devops, monitoring

I want to Monitor the requests of my Java EE App. I just want to see how Many (http) requests per second my application gets. And also to see the failed requests. At the end I want to visualize it on my Grafana Board. So which Tools/Frameworks are Good for my plan? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for once you can use MoSKito: http://www.moskito.org.
For the requests part you can integrate moskito-webui which will then provide a filter which will capture every URL and calculate results for it.
You can also monitor execution time of your classes with AOP and CDI support.
See for more details:
https://www.moskito.org/integration.html
and https://anotheria.net/blog/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/ (the last one is for spring, but it works in a similar way).